# Keep the Script folder light, clean and organized in my asp.net MVC solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I usually store my personal javascripts in sub folders under Scripts (see the screenshot below). This way of doing allows me to keep the Script folder clean, light and easy to organize. This is my personal point of view. Now I don't know what to do with all the other scripts (jquery, MicrosoftAjax, ...) **and I wonder how other people organize the Script folder**. I think I'll store them in subfolders like jquery folder or General, or ...

[image]

Can you give me your point of view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend a tool called Minify, which will combine and minify all your JS files so you only need one `<script src="/min/f=mod1.js,mod2.js,mod3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` tag.

You can store your JS files however you want, even outside the web root, and it won't matter because they'll simply be referenced in an associative PHP array in the Minify groupsConfig.php file. **I'd recommend this specifically for your situation.** For example:

```
'js' => array(
            '//Scripts/Cart/cartScript.js',
            '//Scripts/tiny_mce/common.js',
            '//Scripts/weblog.js',
            // and so on...
            )
```

Then your script tag would look like:

```
<script src="/min/g=js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

After Minify comines and minifies your code, it will cache it on your server so subsequent requests will hit the cache file so the PHP won't need to process. Of course the primary benefit of this tool is that your users only download a single JavaScript file from your server instead of being forced to open several http connections to download multiple files, which is usually a major performance deterrent.

http://code.google.com/p/minify/

Comment: I was not aware of this nice tool. Thanks. I'll take a look on it.

Answer (score 2):

I put in a folder called js/libs, personally prefer to use lower case.
To solve the problem of cdn use a code like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.6.2.min.js">\/script>')</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that for public facing websites, hosting common javascript libraries on a CDN is better for performance. For example, using [Microsoft](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx) or [Google](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/).

If you still wish to host them internally, there really is no performance difference in subfolders so it's down to personal preference. If you find it neater using a `General` subfolder or a `jQuery` and `Microsoft` subfolder then go with that approach.

Comment: Thanks for your response. At this time of my development, I prefer not host my common javascript on CDN because sometimes I don't have any internet connection and thus my VS project would not start (for debugging). I know it is a personal preference but I'm just curious to know how other people organize their javascript.